# Regex for URL C#

Tags: c#, regex, url-parsing

In my C# program I wrote a Google Search Function, which works by fetching the source from each page and getting the URLs via regex.

My actual Regex is:

```
(?:(?:(?:http)://)(?:w{3}\\.)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9/;\\?&=:\\-_\\$\\+!\\*'\\(\\|\\\\~\\[\\]#%\\.])+)
```

This works good at the moment, but I get for example URLs like `http://www.example.com/forums/arcade.php?efdf=332`

I just want to get in this case the URL without the `?efdf=332` at the end.

So how should I change the regex?

Comment: Hi Omegavirus, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've noticed that you went to a lot of trouble to get your regex formatted correctly, but you could have had it a lot easier. Just paste the original regex, mark it and press Ctrl-K. This will format the text as verbatim text (like HTML `pre` tag). Much less potential for errors.

Comment: oh i didn't know that, thanks ;)
and the regex is from my c# program so \ are escaped. forgot to say that.

Comment: In C#, use verbatim strings (`@"foo"`) with regexes. Then you don't have to escape your backslashes. You'll go crazy otherwise. Regexes are hard enough to read already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9/;&=:_$+!*'()|~\[\]#%.\\-]+
```

does the same as your regex (I've removed a lot of unnecessary cruft) but stops matching a link before a `?`.

In C#:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"http://(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9/;&=:_$+!*'()|~\[\]#%.\\-]+")
```

That said, I'm not sure this is such a good way of matching URLs (what about `https`, `ftp`, `mailto` etc.?)

Comment: many thanks ;)
https etc is no problem cause i won't need them.. http is all :)

just tested your regex and its nearly working. but now i get urls like http://www.blabla.com/forums/&ampblabla

how to filter these also out?

Comment: So you just want domain + path without any parameters?

Comment: Try removing the `&` from the regex. Same with any other characters you don't want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class to access various parts of the URL and either remove the query string from the end, or concatenate the parts you want.